# Remove class from all div elements

Tags: jquery

I have a group of topics. I'm trying to loop through them and add the class "glow" to them one at a time depending on the seconds I specify. When one element gets glow, the previous element should no longer glow.

```
<div class="center" id="topics">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="topic" id="fade1">Introduction and Overview</div>
        <div class="topic" id="fade4">Topic 6</div>
        <div class="topic" id="fade7">Accounting Topic</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="topic" id="fade2">Topic Navigation</div>
        <div class="topic" id="fade5">Topic Changes</div>
        <div class="topic" id="fade8">Topic 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="topic" id="fade3">More Topics</div>
        <div class="topic" id="fade6">Elements</div>
        <div class="topic" id="fade9">Conclusion</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm defining the seconds intervals for them to glow. So when one glows, the rest should no longer glow.

```
$.glowElements([
    {target: "#fade1", seconds: 4},
    {target: "#fade2", seconds: 9},
    {target: "#fade3", seconds: 20},
    {target: "#fade4", seconds: 22}, 
    {target: "#fade5", seconds: 23},
    {target: "#fade5", seconds: 24}                              
]);
```

And my code that processes the glow:

```
$.glowElements = function(list){
    if(!USE_AUDIO){ return; }

    $(list).each(function(index, element){ 
        // remove all glows first
        $(".row > div").removeClass("glow");


        timers.push(setTimeout(function(){ 
            $(element.target).addClass("glow");
        },element.seconds * 1000));
    });
}
```

My `$(".row > div").removeClass("glow");` is not working? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Easy way**

```
$(".glow").removeClass("glow");
```

and then add

```
$(element.target).addClass("glow");
```

Comment: Oh boy, I feel silly for thinking about this differently. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you Mike!